# Why is external javascript library blocking javascript on my page?

Tags: javascript, external

Here's a very simple question that my simple mind can't answer: why isn't the anonymous and onload function below being run when I load in the external library?   I am missing something really, really basic.  Library.js has only one line: console.log('library').  How much more basic can one get?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/library.js' />
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        console.log('anon');
    })();

    window.onload = function () {
        console.log('onload');
    } ();   
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script syntax is invalid. You should have a separate closing tag instead of the self-closing version.

```
                                           <!--------- v --------->
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/library.js'></script>
```

---

You also have an issue in that you're invoking the `onload` function immediately.

```
window.onload = function () {
    console.log('onload');
}/* () */;
 // ^^---remove these to assign the function instead of invoking it.
```

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes, a script element is not a void element.

Comment: Thanks for answering such a basic question!  I've done most of my javascript programming in a vendor's environment that let me get away with a self-closing script tag.  And thanks for the reminder about invoking the onload right away.